# Unable to run Airbyte on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, airbyte

I am trying to run Airbyte on EC2, but when I follow the official guideline (https://docs.airbyte.com/deploying-airbyte/on-aws-ec2/) the part with

```
sudo yum install -y docker-compose-plugin
docker compose version
```

gives that:

```
docker: 'compose' is not a docker command.
```

Is there any other way to install docker compose V2 (not docker-compose) on an EC2?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and ended up doing it this way:

```
DOCKER_VER=v2.20.3
curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/$DOCKER_VER/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose 
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
docker-compose version
```

Answer (score 0):

change docker compose in run-ab-platform.sh to docker-compose.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

On the `run-ab-platform.sh` I changed `docker compose` to `docker-compose` at:

```
########## Dependency Check ##########
if ! docker compose version >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; then
  echo -e "$red_text""docker compose v2 not found! please install docker compose!""$default_text"
  exit 1
fi
```

And

```
docker compose up $dockerDetachedMode
```

So it is now like:

```
if ! docker compose-version >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; then [...]
```

and

```
docker-compose up $dockerDetachedMode
```